# finding a polynomial s(x) of degree 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> For $f(x) = -\frac{1}{4}x^3+2768x^3-33088x^2-1536x+644$,
>   find a polynomial function of degree $2$ such that $f'(x)=(x-8)s(x)$ for $x\in [−12,12]$.

I understand that a degree of 2 means the function may have 2 zeroes and 1 stationary point. 
So far $f(x)=s(x^2-8x)$. Then that is substituted into the above equation.

Comment: the first term is most likely $x^4$ rather than $x^3$

Comment: Why does $s(x^2-8x)$ make sense?  $s$ is a function (polynomial), so you can't bring the $(x-8)$ into the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**
Assuming you mean $f(x)=−\frac14x^4+2768x^3−33088x^2−1536x+644$, you have
$$
f'(x) = -x^3+3\cdot 2768 x^2 - 2\cdot 33088 x - 1536,
$$
so can you now actually divide $f'(x)$ by $x-8$?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Why would we divide f'(x) by x-8?

Comment: @kimmy because $s(x) \approx \frac{f'(x)}{x-8}$, but I hope you had figured this out already